# Spartacus loads incorrect base site

Tags: spartacus-storefront

The Spartacus seems to not update the base site in some scenarios when it is loaded with SSR. This happens mostly when we had just deployed the app or, in some cases, when you navigate from one site to another.

To reproduce this issue, you have to configure at least two sites on SAP Commerce and it's recommended to edit the "hosts" file in the local machine, to access the production-like URL. For example:

```
127.0.0.1 yourFirstDomain.local
127.0.0.1 yourSecondDomain.local
```

Then, run the Spartacus with SSR, access one of the sites, and edit the URL to access the second one.

To test to see if the base site was updated, I subscribed to the Spartacus base site service and logged the base site Id. When I access the first site, it logs the correct Id. But when I access the second site, editing the URL, the log does not occur and, although the URL changes correctly, the site (data, look, and feel) doesn't change and remains as the first one.

Is this a bug or something that could be configured?

Comment: Hello, are you familiar with docs below?
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/configuring-base-url/ & 
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/contributor-setup/#configuring-your-back-end-url-and-base-site

Comment: Hi, @MichałGruca, in reality, we have four base sites:

(something.com,
something.com/special1,
something.com/special2 and
subdomain.something.com)

All configuration resides on the backend. The sites work fine 99.99% of the time. But in some cases, when we deploy Spartacus, the first access to, let's say, subdomain.something.com renders the site corresponding to something.com. This also happens in the local machine when we run with SSR, as described above.